# Jqueryui prevent event stacking

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jqueryui's drop effect to show an element on mouseenter and hide it on mouseleave. Problem is if you mouse in an out of an element a few times the events stack up and cause it to loop through hiding/showing when you are no longer mousing in/out of the element.

I wanna know if there is a built in way to jquery ui to pause or stop an effect in process and start another to prevent stacking. If anyone also has a link to more functionality of controlling jqueryui functionality that would be swell ( main site just shows how to use an effect not really manipulate it much as far as I can tell ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To stop an effect or animation that's in progress call [`$(..).stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("#divHover").hover(
function(){
    $("#divHidden").stop(true,true).show(100);
}, 
function(){
    $("#divHidden").stop(true,true).hide(100);
});
```

the demo i'm using hide, but, its up to you to decide what to use

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hfpVc/38/